# Segmentation faults in C with fopen?? (not exactly sure what's causing the error)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fopen, fault

So here's my code for my main()

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 3) {
    puts("Invalid number of args in the input. Sorry.");
    return 0;
  }
  if (doesItExist(argv[2]) == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  FILE *fpoint;
  char yesorno[2];
  tail = (WordN) malloc(sizeof(struct WordNode));
  tail->word = "";
  tail->first = (FileN) malloc(sizeof(struct FileNode));
  (tail->first)->freq = -1;
  ftw(argv[2], tokeForMe, 1);
  /**
  fpoint = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if(fpoint != NULL) { // file exists give user option to overwrite or rename
    getInput("Do you want to overwrite the file? Enter only either Y or N nothing else\n", yesorno, 2);
    if(yesorno[0] == 'N' || yesorno[0] == 'n') {
      puts("All right. Not going to proceed with the program");
      return 0;
    }
    else if(yesorno[0] != 'Y' && yesorno[0] != 'y') {
      puts("You inputted some other character, try again \n");
      getInput("Do you want to overwrite the file? Enter Y or N. Do not enter anything other than 1 Y or 1 N \n", yesorno, 2);
    }
  }
  fclose(fpoint);
  **/
  FILE *index;
  index = fopen(argv[1], "w");

  //puts("here");
  writeToIndex(index, tail->next); //tail is pointing to the first word node
  puts("there");
  if (doesItExist(argv[1]) == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  fclose(index);
  TailTerminate();
  return 0;
}
```

The code seg faults when I uncomment the part when I make a file pointer to read argv[1] to find out whether the user wants to overwrite the file specified in argv[1].

The program itself is just a program that makes a sort of indexer out of a directory of files and then prints it out. The directory path is specified in argv[2] and the path to print out the index is specified in argv[1].

Can someone help me with this? The rest of the program (the Tail nodes and such) are only to  make a sort of list the words and frequencies that appear in the program.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show all the functions called from `main` (`getInput`?), and they may content errors. From your commented code, I can only say that you wrote something like this:

```
FILE *f = fopen(...);
if (f != NULL)
{
    /* use f */
}
fclose(f);
```

But it should be like this:

```
FILE *f = fopen(...);
if (f != NULL)
{
    /* use f */
    fclose(f);
}
```

That is, do not call `fclose()` with a `NULL` pointer.